# selenium count divs inside one div

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I want to count divs inside one div with selenium.

[image]

This is my code so far, but I don't understand why this is not working. It returns length of 0.

```
available = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='sc-AykKC.sc-AykKD.slug__RaffleContainer-sc-10kq7ov-2.eujCnV']/div"))
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML snippet as code in your question?

Answer (score 2):

To count `<div>` tags with value of *alt* attribute as **Closed** within its parent `<div>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `text()`:

  ```
  available = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[text()='List']//preceding::div[1]//div[@alt='Closed']"))
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  available = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[contains(., 'List')]//preceding::div[1]//div[@alt='Closed']"))
  ```

Ideally, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using `text()`:

  ```
  available = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='List']//preceding::div[1]//div[@alt='Closed']"))))
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  available = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(., 'List')]//preceding::div[1]//div[@alt='Closed']"))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
div = d.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class='sc-AykKC.sc-AykKD.slug__RaffleContainer-sc-10kq7ov-2.eujCnV']')

res = list(div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'div'))

print(len(res))
```